# TimeStamp каждый раз отличается при открытии активити

Tags: android, timestamp

Есть активити с двумя `TextView`, нажимая на которые пользователь должен выбрать начальную и конечную дату. Время не выбирается. При открытии активит в лог выводу `timestamp` из первого календаря и из второго. Но они каждый раз разные, хотя по мне они каждый раз должны быть одинаковые, если дата не меняется. Или я что-то не так понимаю в работе с `timestamp`?

Например открываю активити, в обеих `TextView` дата 09 декабря 2019, а

```
mills1 = mills2 = 1575892457
```

Если закрыть и открыть еще раз активити, то в обеих `TextView` дата 09 декабря 2019, а `mills1 = mills2 = 1575892516`

```
public class ShowListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tab1ModelAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
    private TextView txtDate1;
    private TextView txtDate2;

    private Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    private Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    private long mills1 = 0;
    private long mills2 = 0;

    private RecyclerView rvList;
    private AppViewModel viewModel;
    private Tab1ModelDao tab1ModelDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_list);

        txtDate1 = findViewById(R.id.txtDate1);
        txtDate2 = findViewById(R.id.txtDate2);

        rvList = findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).getOrientation()));

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AppViewModel.class);
        tab1ModelDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).tab1ModelDao();

        setInitialDateTime();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        txtDate1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            new DatePickerDialog(ShowListActivity.this, d1,
                    calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                    .show();
        });

        txtDate2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            new DatePickerDialog(ShowListActivity.this, d2,
                    calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                    .show();
        });



    }

    private void showList() {
        Tab1ModelAdapter adapter = new Tab1ModelAdapter();
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        viewModel.showFieldsForDate(tab1ModelDao);
        viewModel.getList().observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<Tab1Model>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagedList<Tab1Model> list) {
                adapter.submitList(list);
            }
        });
        rvList.setAdapter(adapter);

        TestClass t = new TestClass(mills1, mills2);
        viewModel.filter.setValue(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {

    }

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d1=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            setInitialDateTime();
        }
    };

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d2=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            setInitialDateTime();
        }
    };

    private void setInitialDateTime() {
        txtDate1.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this,
                calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),
                DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));

        txtDate2.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this,
                calendar2.getTimeInMillis(),
                DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));

        mills1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
        Log.d("m1 " , mills1 + "");
        mills2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
        Log.d("m2 " , mills2 + "");

        showList();
    }
}
```

Выбор даты

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        String str_date=monthOfYear+"-"+dayOfMonth+"-"+year;
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

        try {
            Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
            mills=date.getTime()/1000L;
            Log.d("Mills 1 ", mills + "");
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        long mills2 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
        Log.d("Mills 2 ", mills2 + "");

        setInitialDateTime();
    }
};
```

Comment: В чем заключается задача? А то вопрос про одно, а в комментариях речь уже о другом.

Comment: @Эникейщик задача из введенной даты (без времени) получить таймштамп этой даты на начало дня, чтобы выборку из БД начиналась за весь день

Answer (score 2):

timestamp это **не дата**. Это количество **секунд**, прошедших с 00:00 1 января 1970 года по UTC. Т.е. год, месяц, день, час, минута, секунда. Логично, что при открытии каждый раз меняются как минимум секунды.

Первое значение (1575892457) это 2019-12-09, 11:54:17. А второе (1575892516) : 2019-12-09, 11:55:16. Между двумя стартами активити (точнее, вызовами функции `getTimeInMillis()`) прошло 59 секунд.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы при каждом открытии в mills1 и mills2 было то значение timestamp дата которого указано в txtdat1 и txtdat2

Comment: Сохранить значение в Shared Preferences, например, и потом оттуда считывать.

Comment: Дело в том, что в БД я записываю данные указывая в поле date timestamp в секундах. При открытии activity данные выводятся в RecyclerView по запросу из Dao, где в запросе в условии есть dat1 и dat2 (параметры, которые пользователь указывает в активити). Сохранять в "Shared Preferences" имеет ли смысл?

Comment: Пробую передавать часы и минуты равные 0, все равно не каждый раз разный timestamp. Если дата одна и та же всегда, время и минуты равны 0, наверное всегда должен быть один и тот же таймштапм. Но у меня это не так. Если выбрать даты с 08.12.2019 по 09.12.2019, то данные отображаются, хотя все записи добавлены за 09.12.2019 и дата в поле date для всех записей 09.12.2019

Comment: есть [такой вариант преобразования](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453081/7566397) даты в таймштамп. Последние две строчки лишние, значение output и будет timestamp в формате SQL

Comment: В вопрос добавил метод, где пользователь выбирает дату и таймштамп записывается в перменную. Способ, который вы указали в ссылке и способ, который у меня был. Во втором способе, время не выбирается, только дата. Можете объяснить отличия этих методов? Первый способ переводит просто дату без учета времени в таймштамп, а второй с учетом времени или как? В итоге Mills 2 отличается от Mills 1, хотелось бы узнать почему и как все же правильнее, второй день пытаюсь реализовать выборку. Видимо я записывал таймштамп неправильно или что-то еще

Comment: И если я добавляю запись, получив timestamp способом, который по ссылке, то дата получается 09.11.2019, хотя я выбираю 09.12.2019

Comment: @ПУТЯ месяцы в андроид (класс Calendar) считаются с 0 (0 - январь), нужно прибавлять 1 чтобы получить календарное число месяца для парсинга даты. способ по ссылке должен возвращать коректный таймштамп с временем 00:00'00, это не трудно проверитт сделав обратное преобразования таймштампа в полную дату и время

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. С датами не приходилось работать в андроид, да и в java, поэтому куча вопросов(